# USB wifi authenticates, mini PCI wifi does not

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers

I have an HP Envy 300 (desktop) running Ubuntu 14.04.

I have both a mini PCI wifi/bluetooth card (Broadcom BCM43228) and USB wifi.

I can see both wireless options in the Networks component of System.

The USB wifi connects both to the unsecured network across the street as well as my secured (WPA/WPA2) network.

The PCI wifi will not authenticate.  It sees all the wireless networks available, I can ask it to connect to the unsecured connection across the street and it just doesn't connect.  If I ask it to connect to my secured connection, I type in the password and get an authentication error.

I updated the BCM driver yesterday (after which, the PCI wifi does now show up in Networks).

Any other suggestions?  FWIW, I had the same behavior when I was attempting to use the PCI wifi when running Windows when the system came out of the box (the PCI card was "factory installed").

Comment: dbadmin@Envy:~$ sudo lspci -nn | grep 0280
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
dbadmin@Envy:~$

Comment: *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7c00000-f7c03fff

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` if `uname -a` shows a 3.13 kernel, if it shows a 3.16 kernel then download from http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/bcmwl-kernel-source as the [ubuntu forums broadcom sticky](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110)
shows that bcmwl-kernel-source as the correct driver for your chipset

Comment: 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]

Comment: Followed the directions in the sticky, installed the noted driver above and same behavior.  It will not authenticate on the open wifi network - it says 'Connecting' and then just comes back as Not Connected

Comment: I'd like to be able to use this PCI card to use WoWLAN (which doesn't work on my USB Wifi).

Comment: I would try using the utopic version to see if any improvements were made to the driver